# PrepareForReuse() only for one indexPath

Tags: ios, swift

I bumped into a problem when I need to set `textField` value of the last cell to `nil` when I start scrolling my `tableView`. And when I scroll little, like 1cm down and press the `button` which reloads data of my `tableView` `textField` become nill even if there is 2 cells on a screen.

So basically I need to reuse only my LAST cell which is LAST element of my array. And not to touch other cells.

**Code of `cellForRow`:**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "STAgentSplitTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! STAgentSplitTableViewCell
    let splits = self.agentSplits[indexPath.row]

    if splits.from != nil && splits.to  != nil && splits.percent != nil {
        if indexPath.row == agentSplits.endIndex-1 {
            cell.startValueCell.text = String(describing: splits.from!)
            cell.endValueCell.text = String(describing: splits.to!)
            cell.percentCell.text = "\(String(describing: splits.percent!))"
        }
        else {
            cell.startValueCell.text = "$"+String(describing: splits.from!.withCommas())
            cell.endValueCell.text = "$"+String(describing: splits.to!.withCommas())
            cell.percentCell.text = "\(String(describing: splits.percent!))%"
        }
        if self.agentSplits[indexPath.row].to! == -1 {
            cell.endValueCell.text = "Infinity"
        }
    }

    if indexPath.row == agentSplits.endIndex-1 {
        if from > to {
            to = from
            cell.endValueCell.text = String(describing: splits.from!)
        }

        if percent > 100 {
            percent = 100
            agentSplits[indexPath.row].percent! = 100
            cell.percentCell.text = "\(String(describing: splits.percent!))"
        }
    }

    cell.selectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    if splits.isSelected == true {
        cell.selectButton.isSelected = true
    }
    else {
        cell.selectButton.isSelected = false
    }

    if splits.isCustom == true {
        cell.startValueCell.placeholder = "Custom"
        cell.endValueCell.placeholder = "Custom"
        cell.percentCell.placeholder = "%"
    }
    else {
        cell.startValueCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.endValueCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.percentCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    cell.startValueCell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fromTextFieldValueChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    cell.endValueCell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toTextFieldValueChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    cell.percentCell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(percentTextFieldValueChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: "So basically I need to reuse only my LAST cell which is LAST element of my array. And not to touch other cells." Wrong. You should always reuse cells. The problem is merely that you are not reusing them _properly_. Your `cellForRow` is incorrectly written.

Comment: I mean that I want to left alone other cells and perform clear only for my last cell. Imagine: I opened my ViewController, filled my textFields, made a small scroll down, released it and then tapped reloadData() button. All the data from my model disappeared because prepareForReuse() was called and set them all to NIL.

Comment: @matt and why my cellForRow is incorrectly written?

Comment: Any time you have `if` without `else`, or you do anything without checking whether you've done it already (as in your `addTarget`), you are writing it incorrect. Keep in mind that the cell is _reused_; this method may _already_ have run once on this cell, so you need to take account of what it may already have done to the cell. You are not doing that.

Comment: Also you are confusing yourself, I think, by using both `cellForRow` and `prepareForReuse`. In general I advise _never_ using `prepareForReuse`; do all the work in `cellForRow` so that you can see it all in one place and can base it on what row this _is_.

Comment: You mean in "celForRow" I should check if cell exist and perform all actions there and then in else write down default values instead of prepareForReuse()?

Comment: You know the cell _exists_. You just need to make sure you supply correct values in _every_ case depending the row, and that you don't do _again_ something that you have done already. Okay, now I'm just repeating myself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.